# Playing music files in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a list of music files that should be played with my Android application. Actually user selects a list of files to be played for a specified time, and then clicks on 'start button'. Please tell me how I can implement it so that the following requirements are met:

1. The program should work, even if power button is pressed or the display is turned off.
2. Music files should be played one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order that the music continue after your application activities exit, you need to implement the playing itself as a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html) (specifically, a [started service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#CreatingAService)). For playing the music, take a look at [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). There is a discussion of using a MediaPlayer in a Service in the [Media Player guide topic](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any sample code? How I can pass the file names to service class?

Comment: @FaridAla Take a look at the [Random Music Player](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/RandomMusicPlayer/index.html) sample project. It does most of what you want (I think).

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that what's I'm looking for. Again thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To play audio files, you can use Android's `MediaPlayer` class.

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(audioFilePath);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

This code snippet will load and play a single audio file. Take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for `MediaPlayer` to figure out how you might be able to leverage it for what you're trying to accomplish specifically.